# Using value in Eloquent model instead of model ID

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am probably just doing this wrong but I am trying to find out what the best way to handle this is.

I have an Appointment model and within that model, I have a few relationships as it pertains to other tables:

```
public function services() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\AppointmentService');
}
public function notes() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\AppointmentNote');
}   
public function statues() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\AppointmentStatus');
}        
public function blocks() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Block', 'id');
}
```

`services(), notes(), statues()` all work fine because they contain an `appointment_id` however, `blocks` is just a means to show the text of the block and does not contain appointment information.

appointments table contains a `block` column that uses the `blocks` table ID.

`id, block '1', '8-10' '2', '9-12' '3', '12-3' '4', '3-5'`

so when I do something like `$appointment->block->block` I would like to display the string of the value that is in the `appointment` table and not pass it the `appointment_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify keys for relationship as follows

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Block', 'id', 'block');
```

According to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

> Additionally, Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a
> value matching the id (or the custom $primaryKey) column of the
> parent. In other words, Eloquent will look for the value of the user's
> id column in the user_id column of the Phone record. If you would like
> the relationship to use a value other than id, you may pass a third
> argument to the hasOne method specifying your custom key: